# Datagrid column header values are missing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Beginner question. I have following `XAML` in my WPF form.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="GridTable" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding GridDataSource}" 
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE2E2E2" 
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFE2E2E2" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
              Margin="10,140,214,10" 
              SelectionChanged="GridTableSelectionChanged" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{Binding Selection}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding XmlFile}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Result}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

    </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel Code

```
    public string Selection
    {
        get { return "Selection"; }
    }

    public string XmlFile
    {
        get { return "Xml File"; }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get { return "Result"; }
    }

    private DataTable CreateDataSource()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        var dc = new DataColumn(Selection, typeof(bool));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn(XmlFile, typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn(Result, typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        return dt;
    }
```

I am using this datatable as source for my grid after populating data in it.

I expect when I run my application I should be able to see a datagrid with 3 columns with headers `Selection`, `XmlFile` and `Result` as the per the binding values. But I see is only grid with no columns. Can anyone help me to understand whats wrong in this?

Also I want to attach a datasource `GridDataSource` to the grid. This datatable has 3 columns with same names as of grid columns and some related data. When I load some data in datatable and notify it to view, then I see already present 3 empty columns and then more 3 columns of my datatable. Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong with my code. Let me know if you need more info.

**Edit**

Also I noticed, when my `AutoGenerateColumns` tag is set to true then I see additional 3 columns of my datatable in DataGrid along with 3 empty columns. And when AutoGenerateColumns` tag is set to false, then I don't see any data and only see 3 empty columns.

Comment: Can you post the underlying VM, please? Are you getting any `BindingExpression` errors in your debug out window?

Comment: see edit....out for lunch for an hour :)

Comment: Enjoy your lunch - What's about the `BindingExpression` errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors while debugging....

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're binding `DataGridColumn.Header` which means that your `GridDataSource` should expose 3 properties (`Selection`, `XmlFile` and `Result`) to be displayed in column headers, not values. If I understand your problem and data model, I think what what you want to bind is `Binding`, not `Header`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selection" Binding="{Binding Selection}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="XmlFile" Binding="{Binding XmlFile}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Result" Binding="{Binding Result}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

also `DataGrid` has `AutoGenerateColumns` option , which might be of a use here, that will create columns automatically for you based on the attached data source so you don't have to specify `DataGrid.Columns` manually

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ..../>
```

Comment: I think no....I am trying to bind the Header Text to a property in ViewModel. Now again, I am trying to bind the datasource of grid to a datatable. As I want to use the existing columns of datagrid, I prepared the datatble with same column names so that the binding is successful.

Comment: Technically, when binding `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` I need a `DataRowView` in ViewModel but I just have a string as of now. And I have all my data in a datatable instead.

Comment: But then auto generate columns will do what you're looking for. It will bind data and create your column header for you. [Here](http://db.tt/cwhpUhQo) is my simple example which will bind to `DataTable` from my model view and auto generate columns. Since your column header is set at creation point from your property you don't have to bind it again.

Comment: I have achieved that. Now I want to use the static datacolumns instead of dynamic ones. It will help me to define the width of columns, color of column cells and etc. Is it possible to do this with dynamic columns?